# Authentication and Connection refused error while crawling using nutch

Tags: nutch

I am trying to crawl some urls using Nutch 1.7, but I'm facing

1. authentication issues and
2. connection refused exception.
3. According to the logs I could see that it is trying to authenticate with NTLM, but after that it shows "Redirect required" and finally releasing the connection... (could be seen in logpart-1)

According to the Nutch tutorial in

> http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/HttpAuthenticationSchemes#A_note_on_NTLM_domains

1. I have set the auth-configuration in `httpclient-auth.xml`  file:
2. Defined `httpclient` property in both `nutch-site.xml` and `nutch-default.xml`

   plugin.includes
   protocol-(httpclient|http)|urlfilter-
   regex|parse-(text|html|tika)|index-(more|basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-
   opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)
3. Also have defined the auth configuration file in `nutch-site.xml`.

   http.auth.file
   httpclient-auth.xml
   Authentication configuration file for 'protocol-httpclient' plugin.

But there is no success for me!

Am I not configuring the authentication in proper way or I am missing something?

Can anyone please help me with the proper required authentication configuration in Nutch?

---

Attaching complete `hadoop.log`:

`logpart-1:authentication`

```
2014-04-16 05:11:23,712 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Authorization required
2014-04-16 05:11:23,712 DEBUG auth.AuthChallengeProcessor - Using authentication scheme: ntlm
2014-04-16 05:11:23,731 DEBUG auth.AuthChallengeProcessor - Authorization challenge processed
2014-04-16 05:11:23,733 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Authentication scope: NTLM <any realm>@sp.zzz.com:80
2014-04-16 05:11:23,732 DEBUG fetcher.Fetcher - FetcherThread spin-waiting ...
2014-04-16 05:11:23,733 DEBUG fetcher.Fetcher - FetcherThread spin-waiting ...
2014-04-16 05:11:23,733 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Retry authentication
2014-04-16 05:11:23,733 DEBUG fetcher.Fetcher - FetcherThread spin-waiting ...
2014-04-16 05:11:23,734 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Resorting to protocol version default close connection policy
2014-04-16 05:11:23,733 DEBUG cookie.CookieSpec - Unrecognized cookie attribute: name=HttpOnly, value=null
2014-04-16 05:11:23,734 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Should NOT close connection, using HTTP/1.1
2014-04-16 05:11:23,735 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Cookie accepted: "PHPSESSID=9f9378mvh9e720f5o3l0ibc1o7"
2014-04-16 05:11:23,735 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Authenticating with NTLM <any realm>@sp.zzz.com:80
2014-04-16 05:11:23,735 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Redirect required
2014-04-16 05:11:23,735 DEBUG params.HttpMethodParams - Credential charset not configured, using HTTP element charset
2014-04-16 05:11:23,735 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Should close connection in response to directive: close
2014-04-16 05:11:23,735 DEBUG httpclient.HttpConnection - Releasing connection back to connection manager.
2014-04-16 05:11:23,736 DEBUG httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - Freeing connection, hostConfig=HostConfiguration[host=www.xxxportal.com]
2014-04-16 05:11:23,736 DEBUG util.IdleConnectionHandler - Adding connection at: 1397643083736
2014-04-16 05:11:23,736 DEBUG httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2014-04-16 05:11:23,737 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Adding Host request header
2014-04-16 05:11:23,744 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Authorization required
2014-04-16 05:11:23,744 DEBUG auth.AuthChallengeProcessor - Using authentication scheme: ntlm
2014-04-16 05:11:23,744 DEBUG auth.AuthChallengeProcessor - Authorization challenge processed
2014-04-16 05:11:23,744 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Authentication scope: NTLM <any realm>@sp.zzz.com:80
2014-04-16 05:11:23,745 INFO  regex.RegexURLNormalizer - can't find rules for scope 'fetcher', using default
2014-04-16 05:11:23,745 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Credentials required
2014-04-16 05:11:23,745 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Credentials provider not available
2014-04-16 05:11:23,745 INFO  httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Failure authenticating with NTLM <any realm>@sp.zzz.com:80
2014-04-16 05:11:23,745 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Resorting to protocol version default close connection policy
2014-04-16 05:11:23,745 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Should NOT close connection, using HTTP/1.1
2014-04-16 05:11:23,746 DEBUG httpclient.HttpConnection - Releasing connection back to connection manager.
2014-04-16 05:11:23,746 DEBUG httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - Freeing connection, hostConfig=HostConfiguration[host=sp.zzz.com]
```

For few of other links I am getting

> I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect

I am not behind any proxy and I have turned off all the firewall settings in the system still. No idea why I am getting *connection refused exception*.

---

Here also I am not able to find out the exact reason why I am getting connection refused exception.

Please help me to understand the exact problem in this case a well.

`Attaching the complete hadoop.log`!

`logPart2-connection` refused.

```
2014-04-16 05:11:26,443 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher - * queue: www.xxxportal.com
2014-04-16 05:11:26,443 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher -   maxThreads    = 1
2014-04-16 05:11:26,444 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher -   inProgress    = 0
2014-04-16 05:11:26,444 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher -   crawlDelay    = 5000
2014-04-16 05:11:26,444 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher -   minCrawlDelay = 0
2014-04-16 05:11:26,444 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher -   nextFetchTime = 1397643088739
2014-04-16 05:11:26,444 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher -   now           = 1397643086444
2014-04-16 05:11:26,444 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher -   0. www.xxxportal.com/profiles/
2014-04-16 05:11:26,445 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher -   1. www.xxxportal.com/wiki/index.php
2014-04-16 05:11:26,445 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher -   2. www.xxxportal.com/sop/
2014-04-16 05:11:26,560 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Closing the connection.
2014-04-16 05:11:26,560 INFO  httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
2014-04-16 05:11:26,560 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
                at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
                at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
                at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
                at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:140)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:125)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
                at org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.HttpResponse.<init>(HttpResponse.java:94)
                at org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.Http.getResponse(Http.java:154)
                at org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.api.HttpRobotRulesParser.getRobotRulesSet(HttpRobotRulesParser.java:75)
                at org.apache.nutch.protocol.RobotRulesParser.getRobotRulesSet(RobotRulesParser.java:157)
                at org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.api.HttpBase.getRobotRules(HttpBase.java:391)
                at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher$FetcherThread.run(Fetcher.java:676)
2014-04-16 05:11:26,564 INFO  httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request
2014-04-16 05:11:26,565 DEBUG httpclient.HttpConnection - Open connection to www.zzzlearninglounge.com:80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) From the logs it clearly says Authentication failure for NTLM on your particular site.

Here you must first check username/password.

Then Scheme of Auth Basic/NTLM/
And then port on which you want to autheticate

If you validate these 3 point and use correct values then your Authentication problem should get resolved...

Comment: Can you please tell me if there is any way for apache nutch to ignore robots.txt while crawling. I am using nutch 2.2.1. I found that "RobotRulesParser.java"(full path:-src/plugin/lib-http/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/http/api/ 
RobotRulesParser.java) is responsible for the reading and parsing the robots.txt. Is there any way to modify this to ignore robots.txt and go on with crawling?

Comment: At first we should respect the robots.txt file if you are crawling any external sites. Otherwise you are at risk - your IP banned or worse can be any legal case.
2) If your site is internal and not expose to external world then you should change the robots.txt file to allow your crawler.
3) you can try out following option:
AFAIK; In Fetcher.java file ->
if (!rules.isAllowed(fit.u.toString())) { }
This is the block that is responsible for blocking the urls. So you can play around this code block to resolve your issue.